# Rails autocomplete with select2 and ajax doesn't pop any data

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, jquery-select2

I'am trying to make an autocomplete feature for a skills search in my db. I would like to use select2 with ajax request for poping data to the user without refreshing the page.

So far i just suceed to build the select2 form with coffee script but when i try to type something, there is no any result at all. 
[select2 tests screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdW25.png)

I think my problem come from passing data between cofee script and controller with the json, cause i'm not very confortable with that. So, there is my code :

*view.html.erb :*

```
<%= hidden_field_tag(:skill, '', id: 'res_select', class: 'select2 ajax', style: 'width: 100%;', data: { source: search_for_skills_path, placeholder: 'Search for a skill' }) %>
```

*skills_search.cofee* :

```
$(document).ready ->


 $('.select2').each (i, e) =>
    select = $(e)
    options =
      placeholder: select.data('placeholder')

if select.hasClass('ajax') # only add ajax functionality if this class is present
  options.ajax =
    url: select.data('source')
    dataType: 'json'
    data: (term, page) ->
      q: term
      page: page
      per: 25
    results: (data, page) ->
      results: data.resources
      more: data.total > (page * 25) # adding the more: option enables infinite scrolling (select2 will load more content if available)

  options.dropdownCssClass = "bigdrop"

select.select2(options)
```

*skills_search_controller :*

```
def search_for_skills

  @skills = Skill.select([:id, :libelle]).
                          where("libelle like :q", q: "%#{params[:q]}%").
                          order('libelle').page(params[:page]).per(params[:per]) # this is why we need kaminari. of course you could also use limit().offset() instead

    # also add the total count to enable infinite scrolling
    resources_count = Skill.select([:id, :libelle]).
                          where("libelle like :q", q: "%#{params[:q]}%").count

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: {total: resources_count, resources: @skills.map { |e| {id: e.id, text: e.libelle} }} }
    end
end
```

*route.rb :*

```
  get '/search_for_skills', to: 'skills_search#search_for_skills'
```

I used this tutorial for perform this : http://luksurious.me/2013/10/rails-easily-add-autocomplete-to-forms/ and i tried lot of things for few days but i'm desperate to make it working fine, any help will be hugely appreciated :D

Comment: What does your controller method `search_for_skills` return? Does it return correct formatted output or not? Also, be careful while using CoffeeScript, indentation plays a big role. I might be wrong here but do check your indention before executing you app.

Comment: @SusanJoshi hi, thanks for your answer, my controller dosn't return anything, i think this is my ajax request which is never send. I took the coffee code in a tutorial i never played with jquery and coffee so i don't really know how to modify this code, but i tried with others codes this is same result. I saw that i go in the if part but i don't go in the result part. I think there is some troubles with the ajax request